# get value with javascript into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please help me to solve this error

```
<input id="webadd" type="text"></input>
<div id="mydiv">
    <iframe id="frame" src="" width="320px" height="480px"></iframe>
</div>
<button id="button">Load</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function () {
            var web-add=document.getElementById('#webadd').value
            $("#frame").attr("src",+web-add);
        });
    });
</script>
```

this code contain error

Comment: You can't declare a variable with a hyphon(`-`). Also when you get element by id with javascript **don't** use id indicator(`#`)

Comment: what is the code supposed to do? what is the error?

Comment: I revoew - from variable name,...

Comment: no output is error.... user can website name in text box and when click on that button,, that website will load in iframe. that is i want to do @DarkoZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove - from variable name, the + before variable, and the # before the id in getElementById

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function () {
            var webadd=document.getElementById('webadd').value
            $("#frame").attr("src",webadd);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing '+' in

```
$("#frame").attr("src",+web-add); //remove '+' in this line
```

Comment: 'code' $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $("#button").click(function () { 
    var websadd=document.getElementById('webadd').text();
    $("#frame").attr("src",websadd);
   });
  }); 'code'

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the "+" before web-add in your script, and the "-" while declaring variable.

That gives :

```
var webadd=document.getElementById('#webadd').value
$("#frame").attr("src",web-add);
```

Full code :

```
<input id="webadd" type="text"></input>
<div id="mydiv">
    <iframe id="frame" src="" width="320px" height="480px"></iframe>
</div>
<button id="button">Load</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function () {
            var webadd=document.getElementById('#webadd').value
            $("#frame").attr("src",web-add);
        });
    });
</script>
```